# How to copy vector to map in STL in a graceful way

Tags: c++, c++11, vector, dictionary, stl

Currently, I have some data in a vector. currently, I want to transform the vector to a map.
So it will be organize as below(N is even number).

vector: element 1, element 2, element 3, element 4 ... element N.

map: key1: element 1, value1: element 2,  key2: element 3 value2: element 4...

Currently, I just enumerate vector, is there any other graceful way to do it. C++11 is prefer. Thanks.

```
for (int x = 0; x < vec.size(); )
{
    map[vec[x]] = vec[x+1];
    x+=2;
}
```

Comment: `x += 2` can go in the loop header after the second semicolon.

Comment: I can't make head nor tail of your description of what the map should like. Why does it have keys, values *and* elements, and why are the numbers out of order? And how do elements in the vector becomes keys and values in the map?

Comment: You should check for an odd number of elements, unless you are certain that cannot happen.  Otherwise, looks fine.

Comment: I would take note of the comments made by dasblinkenlight and MichaelJ. Otherwise, looks good to me.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your code works (noting Michael J's suggestion to not process the last element if there is an odd number).

There is a small improvement that can be made. The call `map[vec[x]]` constructs an entry using the default constructor of the `value_type`, and then the copy-assignment operator copies the value from `vec[x+1]`.

You could avoid the copy-assignment step by doing:

```
the_map.insert( std::make_pair(vec[x], vec[x+1]) );
```

I think this ends up having the map entry copy-constructed from the pair. In C++11 you can do:

```
the_map.emplace(vec[x], vec[x+1]);
```

which allows the compiler to minimize the amount of copying done. If your object supports move semantics and you want to destroy the vector afterwards, you can even go:

```
the_map.emplace( std::move(vec[x]), std::move(vec[x+1]) );
```

Comment: Because of the return value optimization there is usually no extra copy construction done since std::make_pair returns a temporary. In C++11 both versions don't make extra copies because of move semantics.

Comment: OK thanks for the info. I'm not up to date on exactly what emplacement can do